# Angular table with nested array, "name" displayed in left column, ngFor

Tags: angular, nested, ngfor

I created table

```
 <table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>
        Player 1
      </th>
         <th>
        Player 2
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="background-color:gray" colspan="100%">Avengers </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>General</td>
      <td>Captain America</td>
      <td>Iron Man</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Soldier</td>
      <td>Hulk</td>
      <td>Spiderman</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="background-color:gray" colspan="100%">Justice League </td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>General</td>
      <td>Batman</td>
      <td>Superman</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Soldier</td>
      <td>Flash</td>
      <td>Wonder Woman</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

But I want this table to be based on JSON data and showed by *ngFor.
Also i want all of data to be not hard coded (ex. "Soldier" should be key, so that i can change it from json level).

So i created json:

```
data = [
    {
      name: "Player 1",
      avengers: [
        {
          key: "general",
          value: "Captain America"
        },
        {
          key: "soldier",
          value: "Hulk"
        },
      ],
      justiceLeague: [
        {
          key: "general",
          value: "Batman"
        },
        {
          key: "soldier",
          value: "Flash"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "Player 2",
      avengers: [
        {
          key: "general",
          value: "Iron Man"
        },
        {
          key: "soldier",
          value: "Spiderman"
        },
      ],
      justiceLeague: [
        {
          key: "general",
          value: "Superman"
        },
        {
          key: "soldier",
          value: "Wonder Woman"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

My stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-4-starter-mo7etg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

How to show data in table using *ngFor? Thanks for answers in advance!

Comment: I would transform that data to required data model (2d matrix) and ran single *ngFor

Comment: @Antoniossss Could you help me with this?

Comment: @angularbootstrap2211 you should read this https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data

Comment: @HariHaran I have read, unfortunately not any example similar to my problem :(

Comment: You should separate two tables for Player 1  & Player two otherwise it will be pretty complex to achieve it

Comment: @KamranKhatti Could you help me with this?

Comment: @angularbootstrap2211 how about this [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-4-starter-xcjutb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)?

Comment: @KamranKhatti the table must look like in my demo